# Windows 10 shows Critical_Process_Died after working on partition on Gparted Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

so I was trying to free up disk space using Gparted on Ubuntu 16.04. There are some disk containing unknown label of 128 MiB on it and I wanted to make merge it to other drives to free up some space. However I was cautious of doing this and end up cancelling the action. 
[Here is Gparted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCDIY.png). Unexpectedly, when I try to boot into Windows 10 it shows [Critical_Process_Died error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaZQ7.jpg) Is there a way fixing it through Ubuntu 16.04? Any help appreciated, thanks!

----EDIT
The problem is actually the grub menu from Ubuntu, when I changed the UEFI to enable and changing windows boot order to the first it seems okay. I can login to my windows. Anyhow the grub menu is disable and I have to manually spam f12 in order to get into boot option (which is not GRUB menu.)

Comment: The windows 10 works fine after I re-enable the secure boot UEFI and changing windows boot order to the first. However, I am afraid this problem exist when I re-enable the GRUB menu option on booting.

Comment: The problem persist when I disable EUFI and enable GRUB menu. Can anyone explain how to fix it?